# How to display short value in QComboBox and a long value in it's dropdown?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qcombobox

I'm trying to make a QComboBox display a short value (e.g., '1', '2', or '3'), yet have the dropdown from the combo box display longer values such as "Number One", "Number Two", or "Number Three."

Here's what I have ...

```
QString max_dropdown_len, styleSheet;

max_dropdown_len = QString::number(300);
styleSheet = "QComboBox QAbstractItemView { min-width: %1; }";

cb = new QComboBox();

model = qobject_cast<QStandardItemModel*>(cb->model());
model->setColumnCount(2);
model->appendRow(QList<QStandardItem*>() <<
    (new QStandardItem("Number One")) << (new QStandardItem("1")));
model->appendRow(QList<QStandardItem*>() <<
    (new QStandardItem("Number Two")) << (new QStandardItem("2")));
model->appendRow(QList<QStandardItem*>() <<
    (new QStandardItem("Number Three")) << (new QStandardItem("3")));

view = qobject_cast<QListView*>(cb->view());
view->setModelColumn(0);

cb->setModelColumn(1);
cb->setStyleSheet(styleSheet.arg(max_dropdown_len));

aLayout = new QFormLayout;
aLayout->addRow(new QLabel(tr("Test: ")), cb);

aGroup = new QGroupBox(tr("Testing"));
aGroup->setLayout(aLayout);

return aGroup;
```

The problem is, the combo box only displays a '1', and when I click the arrow to drop down the list, the options are '1', '2', or '3' and not the longer string values.

Am I going about this right in order to display a short value? Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to add the long text as a `UserData`, and establish a delegate to the `QComboBox` that selects the long text.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QComboBox>
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include <QStyledItemDelegate>

class ComboBoxDelegate: public QStyledItemDelegate{
public:
    using QStyledItemDelegate::QStyledItemDelegate;
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const override{
        QStyleOptionViewItem opt(option);
        initStyleOption(&opt, index);
        opt.text = index.data(Qt::UserRole).toString();
        const QWidget *widget = opt.widget;
        QStyle *style = widget ? widget->style() : QApplication::style();
        style->drawControl(QStyle::CE_ItemViewItem, &opt, painter, widget);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QComboBox combo;
    combo.addItem("1", "Number One");
    combo.addItem("2", "Number Two");
    combo.addItem("3", "Number Three");
    combo.setItemDelegate(new ComboBoxDelegate(&combo));
    combo.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using the item model, you have to create a slot which does that:

```
cb->setModelColumn(0);
```

When the item list is displayed, and does that:

```
cb->setModelColumn(1);
```

When the item is hidden.
It would be complicated because a QComboBox does not emit a signal when it is released, so you would have to create your own class.

Instead, using a QListView is simpler:

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    int comboBox_lenght = ui->comboBox->count();

    listView = new QListView(ui->comboBox);

    ui->comboBox->setView(listView);

    for (int i=0; i<comboBox_lenght; ++i){ //fill the combobox with hidden items
        ui->comboBox->addItem(QString::number(i + 1));
        listView->setRowHidden(comboBox_lenght + i, true);
    }

    on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged(ui->comboBox->currentIndex());

    show();
}
```

with the following slot:

```
void Widget::on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged(int index)
{
    ui->comboBox->setCurrentText(QString::number(index + 1));

    return;
}
```

result: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16ZSvaG8req5ztCyqrIup23NQqixYcEpP/view?usp=sharing

Comment: He didn't, but your slot assumes the combo is editable.

Comment: well, since I use a QListView, there's no need to make it editable.
try it or watch the screencast...

Comment: Ok, now I got your point, but you only provided little on the code and without explanation. Your proposed idea is excellent but it needs to be explained :)

Comment: Okay I understand, I'll try my best to explain next time

Answer (score 0):

Most of code in question is going right, but using `QListView` might not be convenient though. This can be done with a `QTableView` which gives a lot of  rich options spared for fine tuning as needed, here is a straightforward implementation using QTableView.

```
QString max_dropdown_len, styleSheet;
max_dropdown_len = QString::number(300);
styleSheet = "QComboBox QAbstractItemView { min-width: %1; }";
QStandardItemModel* model = new QStandardItemModel(this);
model->setColumnCount(2);
model->appendRow(QList<QStandardItem*>() <<
    (new QStandardItem("1")) << (new QStandardItem("Number One")));
model->appendRow(QList<QStandardItem*>() <<
    (new QStandardItem("2")) << (new QStandardItem("Number Two")));
model->appendRow(QList<QStandardItem*>() <<
    (new QStandardItem("3")) << (new QStandardItem("Number Three")));
QTableView* view = new QTableView(this);
view->setModel(model);
ui->comboBox->setModel(model);
ui->comboBox->setModelColumn(0);
ui->comboBox->setStyleSheet(styleSheet.arg(max_dropdown_len));
ui->comboBox->setView(view);
view->horizontalHeader()->setHidden(true);
view->verticalHeader()->setHidden(true);
view->setGridStyle(Qt::NoPen); // Table without Grid
view->setColumnWidth(0,0); // Option: set this width to also show the digits during combo popup, set to 0 to hide them!
```

Comment: Apologies for getting back so late on this. Is this using Qt 4.x? I'm using 5.9. Just trading out the QListView for QTableView is giving me same probs as my OP. I wish I could get this one to work as it's appears simpler to me and fits what I have already implemented.

Comment: To continue the comment above, for the most part, it works right, meaning when showing a '1', the width of the widget is minimal, and when the drop appears, the widths are wider containing the long value. But I am unable to select a value in the drop-down.

Comment: I was not aware that your requirement is for Qt 4.x but I think its ok because its using basic model.

Comment: No requirement for 4.x, I was just wondering because of the setHidden() calls which I don't appear to have. Anyways, doing it this way seemed straight forwards to me, but for some reason I have yet to make it work.

Comment: I think because you are not clicking directly over the text ..  The thing is I only used a raw sample code .. you might need to adjust the width of the selection cell to available pitch.

Comment: Very well, I'll keep at it.

Comment: `setHidden()` is a basic method, it should work. with which Qt version you tested? may be you are missing some includes?

Comment: If I was missing includes, I would expect it not to compile. I'm using 5.9.4-r2. Either way, I comment those out since my real problem is getting the basics to work.

Comment: `setHidden()` is inherited from QWidget ..  see [QHeaderView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html)